# Factory function returning const

Tags: c++

I have a factory for creating containers based on ugly containers

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> containerFactory(const UglyContainer* uglyContainer)
{
    std::vector<T> container(uglyContainer->count);
    Getter getter;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<uglyContainer->count;++i)
    {
        getter(container[i], uglyContainer->values[i]);
    }
    return container;
}
```

How might I go about complementing containerFactory with a factory function which returns const std::vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Const on the returned vector is irrelevant.  Since it is returned by value, it will be copied and const will apply to the usage of the copy.

Since you are creating the vector on the stack in the factory method, you cannot return the vector by reference.

As a matter of robustness of the container Factory, you might consider taking a vector as an argument to the factory method and appending to it to avoid the copy of the vector.

Comment: Uhm, you mean he cannot return the vector by reference, not by value…

Comment: It would be more robust to return by value: when passing in a vector to fill, there may be confusion over what will happen if it's not empty. Any decent compiler should elide the copy; and in C++11, even if elision fails, the return value will be moved rather than copied.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Creating a version that creates a vector and returns it (by value) is a trivial addition to one that takes the vector by reference.  Creating a version that appends from a version that creates is harder and much less efficient.